# sensor_msgs::LaserScan to PCLPointCloud2 in Indigo

Tags: pcl, sensor-msgs, iai-kinect2, hokuyo, pcl-1.7

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi folks,

I want to know how can I convert an sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr& to  an pcl::PCLPointCloud2 object?

Specifically, what libraries (e.g., "pcl/conver.h" or something like that), what functions (e.g., pcl::fromLasertoPoinCloud() or something like that), and intermediary conversion variables, if any (e.g., from laser-->laserToCloud_holder-->PCLPointCloud).

PS: giving me the direct answer right here is 10x more useful than sending me to a "Migration" website, etc. (because I am also reading some of them already).
Sample code/projects is also useful!

Thanks in advanced.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201870/sensor_msgs::laserscan-to-pclpointcloud2-in-indigo/) by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 803 on 2015-01-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The laser_geometry package has a library for projecting laser scans into point clouds: http://wiki.ros.org/laser_geometry

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) on 2015-01-27**:
Hi,
Yes, I saw that, but I'm trying to change from pcl::PCLPointCloud2, and not from sensor_msgs::PointCloud2.

**Comment by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) on 2015-01-27**:
Do you think there is an extra step that I would have to follow to get to PCLPointCloud2 form the conversion from laser to sensor_msgs::PointCloud to convert that data to PCLPointCloud2?
Thanks

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2015-01-27**:
Yes, but those methods are in the PCL library and not in ROS. ROS will take you as far as pcl::PointCloud http://wiki.ros.org/pcl/Overview